# tikz complex mindmap of all disciplines and subdisciplines of knowledge

Tags: tikz-trees, tikz-styles, tikz-qtree, mindmaps, node-connections

I just started using LaTeX yesterday and I am stuck on my very ambitious diagram of all disciplines of knowledge. Problems (some simple, some probably more complicated):

- Can I change the page size to even fit it all?
- Can I center the main parent node?
- Is there a simple way of using sibling angle with a diagram this vast?
- I still haven't added all the nodes to all the disciplines (but see e.g. physics or logic node, they have so many, I don't know how to align them)
- Ultimately connections between sub-disciplines would be nice too, but the vastness is already overwhelming.

Any help and advice is greatly appreciated!

Here's my code so far:

```
     \documentclass[tikz] {standalone}
     \usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
     \usepackage[paperwidth=100cm,paperheight=100cm,hmargin=0cm,vmargin=0cm]{geometry}               
     \begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}

     \path[mindmap, concept color=black, text=white,
       level 1 concept/.append style={level distance=52mm, sibling angle=100},
       level 2 concept/.append style={sibling angle=30},
       level 3 concept/.append style={sibling angle=20}]

     node[concept] {Disciplines}
     [clockwise from=0]
     child[concept color=blue] {
       node[concept] {Humanities}
       [clockwise from=120, level 2 concept/.append style={sibling angle=50}]
          child { node[concept] {Human History} }
          child { node[concept] {Linguistics} }
          child { node[concept] {Literature} }
          child { node[concept] {Arts} }
          child { node[concept] {Philosophy} }
          child { node[concept] {Religion} }
     }
     child[concept color=green!60!black] {
       node[concept] {Social Sciences}
       [clockwise from=0]
       child { node[concept] {Anthropology} }
       child { node[concept] {Archaeology} }
       child { node[concept] {Area studies} }
       child { node[concept] {Cultural and ethnic studies} }
       child { node[concept] {Economics} }
       child { node[concept] {Gender and sexuality studies} }
       child { node[concept] {Geography} }
       child { node[concept] {Political science} }
       child { node[concept] {Psychology} }
       child { node[concept] {Sociology} }
     }
     child[concept color=red] { 
       node[concept] { Natural Sciences} 
       [clockwise from=-110]
       child { node[concept] {Space sciences} }
       child { node[concept] {Earth sciences} }
       child { node[concept] {Biology} }
       child { node[concept] {Chemistry} }
       child { node[concept] {Physics} 
         [concept color=red!60]
         [clockwise from=30]
         child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Acoustics} }
         child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Applied Physics} }
         child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Astrophysics} }
         child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Atomic, molecular and optical physics} }
         child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Biophysics} }
         child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Computational physics} }
         child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Condensed matter physics} }
         child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Cryogenics} }
         child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Electromagnetism} }
         child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Elementary particle physics} }
         child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Fluid dynamics } }
         child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Geophysics} }
         child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Materials science} }
         child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Mathematical physics} }
         child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Medical physics} }
         child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Mechanics} }
         child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Molecular physics} }
         child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Newtonian physics} }
         child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Nuclear physics} }
         child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Optics} }
         child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Plasma physics} }
         child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Quantum physics} }
         child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Solid mechanics} }
         child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Solid state physics} }
         child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Statistical mechanics } }
         child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Theoretical physics} }
         child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Thermodynamics} }
         child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Vehicle dynamics} } }
     }
     child[concept color=orange] { 
       node[concept] { Formal Sciences} 
       [clockwise from=140]
       child { node[concept] {Logic} 
         [concept color=orange!60]
          child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Mathematical Logic} }
          child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Philosophical Logic} }
          child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Logic in Computer Science} } }
       child { node[concept] {Mathematics} 
         [concept color=orange!60]
          child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Algebra} }
          child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Analysis} }
          child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Probability theory} } 
          child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Geometry} }
          child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Number theory} }
          child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Logic and Foundations of mathematics} }
          child [grandchild] {node[concept] {Applied Mathematics} } }
       child { node[concept] {Statistics} }
       child { node[concept] {Systems science} }
     }
     child[concept color=gray] { 
       node[concept] { Applied Sciences and Professions} 
       [clockwise from=0]
       child { node[concept] {Agriculture} }
       child { node[concept] {Architecture and design} }
       child { node[concept] {Business} }
       child { node[concept] {Divinity} }
       child { node[concept] {Education} }
       child { node[concept] {Engineering} }
       child { node[concept] {Environmental studies and forestry} }
       child { node[concept] {Family and consumer sciences} }
       child { node[concept] {Healthcare science} }
       child { node[concept] {Human physical performance and recreation} }
       child { node[concept] {Journalism, media studies and communication} }
       child { node[concept] {Law} }
       child { node[concept] {Library and museum studies}}
       child { node[concept] {Military sciences} }
       child { node[concept] {Public administration} }
       child { node[concept] {Social work} }
       child { node[concept] {Transportation} }
     }


     \end{tikzpicture}
     \end{document}
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Clarisse, welcome to the site! That's a very ambitious project to be starting out with, and I'm not sure that TikZ is really the right tool for this. Have you looked at software like [Gephi](https://gephi.org/) or [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org)? They are specifically made for dealing with complicated graphs, so you might be happier with one of those in the long run.

Comment: First: Welcome to LaTeX!!! And second: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a possible solution.

[image]

Q1: Change the page size to even fit it all ?

A1: Set the paperwidth=xxcm and paperheight=xxcm in geometry properly.

Q2: Center the main parent node ?

A2:(a) Set up Level 1 concept/.style properly. In this case the outermost grandchild  is `applied science` whose level distance=130mm, so this is set for level 1 style. Also there is a total of 5 children, to evenly radiate out, the sibling angle would be 360/5=72 and that is set in level 1 too.

(b) However, for level 2, the child nodes are so different, this solution makes use of

```
set angles for level/.style={level 2/.append style={sibling angle=360/\the\tikznumberofchildren}},
level/.append style={set angles for level=2},
```

to determine the orientation automatically.

(c) If fine tune is desired, use `scope` environment with `transform canvas` option added that can shift the whole mindmap up and down. The origin (0,0) is alway at the `upper left corner` which can be checked by setting `shift ={(0cm,0cm)}` in the code provided.

Q3: Is there a simple way of using sibling angle with a diagram this vast?

A3: As mentioned in A2.

Q4: I still havent added all nodes to all disciplines (but see e.g. physics or logic node, they have so many, i don't know how to align them)

A4: Increase the `level distance` so that each grandchild fans out further forming a bigger circle to gain space in between. See the example of Physics nod and Applied Sciences nodes.

Q5: Ultimately connections between subdisciplines would be nice too, but the vastness is already overwhelming

A5: Assign each node with a < internal name > then use `draw` command to connect these nodes. See the one line example at the last line.

Code

```
    \documentclass{article}%[tikz,border=10pt] {standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
     \usetikzlibrary{mindmap,calc}
    \usepackage[paperwidth=80cm,paperheight=60cm,showframe]{geometry}               

     \begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{scope}[transform canvas={shift ={(30cm,-20cm)}}]%[transform canvas={shift={(1cm,1cm)}]
     \path[mindmap, concept color=black, text=white,
      level 1 concept/.append style={level distance=130mm, sibling angle=72},
      set angles for level/.style={level 2/.append style={sibling angle=360/\the\tikznumberofchildren}},
      level/.append style={set angles for level=2},
      level 3 concept/.append style={level distance=50mm, sibling angle=20},
      L1/.style={level distance=40mm},  % adjust level distance locally  when grandchildren increase
      L2/.style={level distance=60mm},  % adjust level distance locally  when grandchildren increase
]

     node[concept] {Disciplines}   % root node
     [clockwise from=0]
     child[concept color=blue] {node[concept] {Humanities}
       [clockwise from=30]         %, level 2 concept/.append style={sibling angle=50}]
          child { node[concept] {Human History} }
          child { node[concept] {Linguistics} }
          child { node[concept] {Literature} }
          child { node[concept] {Arts} }
          child { node[concept] {Philosophy} }
          child { node[concept] {Religion} }
     }
     child[concept color=green!60!black] {
       node[concept] {Social Sciences}
       [clockwise from=65]
       child[L1] { node[concept] {Anthropology} }
       child[L1] { node[concept] {Archaeology} }
       child[L1] { node[concept] {Area studies} }
       child[L1] { node[concept] {Cultural and ethnic studies} }
       child[L1] { node[concept] {Economics} }
       child[L1] { node[concept] {Gender and sexuality studies} }
       child[L1] { node[concept] {Geography} }
       child[L1] { node[concept] {Political science} }
       child[L1] { node[concept] {Psychology} }
       child[L1] { node[concept] {Sociology} }
     }
     child[concept color=red] {           % extend the arm of natural science 
       node[concept] { Natural Sciences} 
       [clockwise from=90]
       child { node[concept] {Space sciences} }
       child { node[concept] {Earth sciences} }
       child { node[concept] {Biology} }
       child { node[concept] {Chemistry} }
       child[level distance=100mm] { node[concept] {Physics} % extend the arm of physics
         [concept color=red!60,]
         [clockwise from=30]
         child {node[concept] {Acoustics} }
         child {node[concept] {Applied Physics} }
         child {node[concept] {Astrophysics} }
         child {node[concept] {Atomic, molecular and optical physics} }
         child {node[concept] {Biophysics} }
         child {node[concept] {Computational physics} }
         child {node[concept] {Condensed matter physics} }
         child {node[concept] {Cryogenics} }
         child {node[concept] {Electromagnetism} }
         child {node[concept] {Elementary particle physics} }
         child {node[concept] {Fluid dynamics } }
         child {node[concept] {Geophysics} }
         child {node[concept] {Materials science} }
         child {node[concept] {Mathematical physics} }
         child {node[concept] {Medical physics} }
         child {node[concept] {Mechanics} }
         child {node[concept] {Molecular physics} }
         child {node[concept] {Newtonian physics} }
         child {node[concept] {Nuclear physics} }
         child {node[concept] {Optics} }
         child {node[concept] {Plasma physics} }
         child {node[concept] {Quantum physics} }
         child {node[concept] {Solid mechanics} }
         child {node[concept] {Solid state physics} }
         child {node[concept] {Statistical mechanics } }
         child {node[concept] {Theoretical physics} }
         child {node[concept] {Thermodynamics} }
         child {node[concept] {Vehicle dynamics} } }
     }
     child[concept color=orange] { 
       node[concept] { Formal Sciences} 
       [clockwise from=200]
       child { node[concept] {Logic} 
         [concept color=orange!60]
          child [] {node[concept] {Mathematical Logic} }
          child [] {node[concept] {Philosophical Logic} }
          child [] {node[concept] {Logic in Computer Science} } 
               }
       child { node[concept] {Mathematics} 
         [concept color=orange!60]
          child [] {node[concept] {Algebra} }
          child [] {node[concept] {Analysis} }
          child [] {node[concept] {Probability theory} } 
          child [] {node[concept] {Geometry} }
          child [] {node[concept] {Number theory} }
          child [] {node[concept] {Logic and Foundations of mathematics} }
          child [] {node[concept] (a) {Applied Mathematics} } 
              }
       child { node[concept] {Statistics} }
       child { node[concept] {Systems science} }
     }
     child[concept color=gray] { 
       node[concept] { Applied Sciences and Professions} 
       [clockwise from=8]
       child[L2] { node[concept] {Agriculture} }
       child[L2] { node[concept] {Architecture and design} }
       child[L2] { node[concept] {Business} }
       child[L2] { node[concept] {Divinity} }
       child[L2] { node[concept] {Education} }
       child[L2] { node[concept] {Engineering} }
       child[L2] { node[concept] {Environmental studies and forestry} }
       child[L2] { node[concept] {Family and consumer sciences} }
       child[L2] { node[concept] {Healthcare science} }
       child[L2] { node[concept] (b) {Human physical performance and recreation} }
       child[L2] { node[concept] {Journalism, media studies and communication} }
       child[L2] { node[concept] {Law} }
       child[L2] { node[concept] {Library and museum studies}}
       child[L2] { node[concept] {Military sciences} }
       child[L2] { node[concept] {Public administration} }
       child[L2] { node[concept] {Social work} }
       child[L2] { node[concept] {Transportation} }
};
\draw[red,thick,->] (a) -- node[midway]{some text} (b);
     \end{scope}
     \end{tikzpicture}

     \end{document}
```